# Использование WebSocket на хостинге

Tags: веб-программирование, php, websocket, hosting

Можно ли использовать нормально WebSocket на хостинге? Демона не поставить и тем более node.js. Нужно ли запускать скрипт на сервере бесконечно чтоб удержать сокет? Сильная ли нагрузка при этом? Где найти статью по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2):

А что вам мешает создать обработчик сокетных соединений на каком-то бесплатном хостинге для ноды, типа [вот этого?](https://www.nitrous.io/join/X1NhGYO5TDg)

У себя на сайте поставите в джаваскрипт код, который будетчерез сокет.ио или сок.жс подключатся к нему и передавать данные.